# How much current does this device draw?

Tags: current, datasheet, gps

I am using a GPS device. I'm told it's a WD-G-ZX4120, but on the actual device it says it's an ET-318. I heard from somewhere that this device uses 100 to 150mA. However the datasheets seem to say that it uses only a maximum of 42mA. So how much does it actually use?

[Here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB0QFjAB&url=http://gpsd.googlecode.com/files/WD-G-ZX4120.pdf&ei=Ef3JTa2nLPLYiAKHvIymBQ&usg=AFQjCNHf2NCixaifsKOGt9rGznbmzQz85Q&sig2=oq6gn-Frmq2kGJ5nUtRd3g) is the datasheet for the WD-G-ZX4120, and [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://www.globalsat.com.tw/globalsat_admin/new_file_download.php?Pact=FileDownLoad&Pval=1761&ei=afrJTaf3D43RiAKE9aybBQ&usg=AFQjCNFbdMkvavNBVrEeVofIE8k4Y7EmEw&sig2=SqFFisjQYrNboYPX9A2Jdw) is the datasheet for the ET-318. Are these the same thing?

Comment: It's possible that there are high current draw *spikes*, but the average current draw is ~42mA. Therefore, if you measure the device with a current meter that averages over a few seconds, you get one value, and a fast current meter gets the other.

Answer (score 4):

Your link for the `ET-318` doesn't work, but that doesn't matter. If I have contradicting information like this, what you've *been told* (by whom?) and what the device *actually says*, I'd believe the latter.
If the device says `ET-318` and the datasheet for the `ET-318` says 42 mA, why not believe it? Otherwise you might as well never look at datasheets again.

Comment: If his informant is anything like some people I know, they know a current draw from a different GPS and try to act like know-it-alls and tell you that they know the current draw for that specific one, when they are in fact wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you *test* the device to determine its draw. If you can measure it over 50mA while doing something, you have your answer pretty quickly. Besides, you might find out it's 500mA while you're at it, and wouldn't that be interesting!

Comment: why not give some information about how you would test it?

Comment: @Kortuk, I am quite new to the site, I thought that was outside the scope of the question (I assume there is a question somewhere here such as 'how do I measure the draw of a low voltage DC device' or something. Next time I will try to answer more completely.

Comment: @Hemry. As a mod(for atleast 1 more hour) I am just here to help give people steering in answers. Yes, this person did not ask, but if you were to explain it also, it is probably a logical next step. It would also make a much more substantial answer, you already earned my +1 as you are correct, but I think you could have a great answer with more detail. The great part about stack exchange is you can edit in more detail now! You will get even more upvotes, I promise. A great answer is often worth 10.